# multiplying all elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

I want a function to return the product of all the values in a vector, like `sum` but with multiplication instead of addition. I expected this to exist already, but if it does I can't find it. Here's my solution:

```
product <- function(vec){
    out <- 1
    for(i in 1:length(vec)){
         out <- out*vec[i]
    }
    out
}
```

This behaves the way I want it to. For example:

```
> product(1:3)
[1] 6
```

Is there a better way of doing this, either with an existing function or through an improvement to this custom one?

Comment: rcs answered this first, so I deleted my post.  Highly recommend printing out the R reference card.  You can find it here:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf

Comment: R is a natively vectorized language that works better using functional expressions. Think of using `apply` or `prod` or `reduce`. They also will be faster than a for loop.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You want `prod`:

```
R> prod(1:3)
[1] 6
```

Comment: ``prod(1:171)`` hits my limits!

Comment: never too late to discover this kind of function :'D

Comment: It is incredible, how so many years later I find myself looking for a function that replaces the `*` symbol. I was having problems generating my slides with the `xarigan` package, since markdown uses `*` to italicize and bold.

Answer (score 6):

If your data is all greater than zero this is a safer solution that will not cause compute overflows:

```
exp(sum(log(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook use case for a `reduce` function, one of the foundational pillars of functional programming. Try this:

`Reduce(x=1:5, f='*')`

It produces 120 as expected.